# Resuming segmented file transfer

Tags: linux, windows, file-transfer, mirroring, lftp

When I run an [lftp](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html) command like this:

```
mirror --use-pget-n=10 "My Directory"
```

sometimes I find myself in a situation, that the computer was unexpectedly shutdown, say, during a blackout.

After that, if I examine my local folder "My Directory" I see:

- Some of the file from "My Directory" that finished downloading
- Absence of some files that did not start to download
- A single in progress file, eg. "ThisIsAFileThatHappenedToBeInPogressWhenTheBlackoutHappened.bin"
- A single file with segments map of that file above "ThisIsAFileThatHappenedToBeInPogressWhenTheBlackoutHappened.bin.lftp-pget-status"

It feels to me that there should be command that will allow me to continue the segmented download, yet, I cannot figure it out. Here is what I tried:

```
mirror --continue "My Directory"
```

This does not do the segmented download at all, all remaining files are downloaded in a single stream

```
mirror --continue --use-pget-n=10 "My Directory"
```

It also appears to re-start the download of all remaining files in several streams but not of the incomplete file.

What am I doing wrong?

*Note: linux server, windows client, transfer by sftp*

**Update:** After looking at the source code it appears to me that this is [impossible](https://github.com/lavv17/lftp/issues/356). I'm leaving this question up in a hope that someone can suggest a workaround.

Comment: Would this work as a **workaround**: `find local_mirror_dir -name '*.bin' -exec rm {} \;`? Basically, remove all the partial files and download them from scratch.